# Argument 1 passed to Google_Service_Directory_Groups_Resource::insert must be an instance of Google_Service_Directory_Group,

Tags: php, google-directory-api, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to create a group using  [google directory api](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/insert).

But i am getting this error

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Google_Service_Directory_Groups_Resource::insert() must be an instance
>   of Google_Service_Directory_Group, array given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\groups\index.php on line 94 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\groups\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Service\Directory.php
>   on line 2196

I have used this code

```
<?php

include_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

$clientId = 'jkdjdjkdjkdjk';


$serviceAccountName = 'gserviceaccount.com';

$delegatedAdmin = 'myemailid@gmail.com';

$keyFile = 'myfile.p12';


$appName = 'Example App';


$scopes = array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group'
);


$creds = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $serviceAccountName,
    $scopes,
    file_get_contents($keyFile)
);

$creds->sub = $delegatedAdmin;

/**
 * Create Google_Client for making API calls with
 */
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName($appName);
$client->setClientId($clientId);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($creds);


$dir = new Google_Service_Directory($client);


$postBody = array('email'=>'sales_group@domain.com');
    $list = $dir->groups->insert($postBody);
    print_r($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your array in $postBody for:

```
$postBody = new Google_Service_Directory_Group();
$postBody->email = 'sales_group@domain.com';

$list = $dir->groups->insert($postBody);
print_r($list);
```